# Frictionless Wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I'm self-studying S&Z University Physics 12E, and seem hit on a different solution for 5.120, which I'll abbreviate here.

A frictionless mass $m$ rests on a wedge with mass $M$ one another. $M$ rests on a horizontal surface, and is a rigid frictionless wedge inclined at $\alpha$ off the horizontal.

I show that the small mass $m$ should float indefinitely to the right. *Please* help talk me out of my own stupidity!

[image]

#### Forces onto the wedge

Applying Newton's Second Law, I write the following relationships:
$$\sum \vec{F_M} = \hat{n}+\vec{n}_{\text{m onto M}} + \vec{F}_g = M\vec{a}_M$$
where

- $\hat{n}$ is the normal force of the table onto the wedge. $$<0, \hat{n}_y>$$
- $\vec{n}_{\text{m onto M}}$ is the reaction to the normal force of $M$ onto $m$. $$<-n^*\sin(\alpha), -n^*\cos(\alpha)>$$
- $\vec{F}_g$ is simply the weight of the larger mass, $M$.$$<0,-Mg>$$

It is obvious to me, *as an idiot*, that $\hat{n}$, the normal force exerted by the table onto the wedge should be equivalent to the weight of the joint system, so $\hat{n}=<0,\hat{n}_y>=<0,(M+m)g>$

Which vectors out to $$
\begin{array}{cc}
  \Bigg \lbrace & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      Ma_{Mx} = \\
      Ma_{My} =
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{array}{cc}
      -n^*\sin(\alpha) \\
      \hat{n}_y - n^*\cos(\alpha)-Mg
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$

The next *probably wrong goofiness* I do is to set $Ma_{My} = 0$ which provides an expression for $n^*$, solely in terms of $m$ which is elegant. Written explicitly, $0=\hat{n}_y - n^*\cos(\alpha)-Mg=(M+m)g - n^*\cos(\alpha)-Mg$ distributing $g$ gives $mg = n^*\cos(\alpha)$ and so $$n^* = {mg \over \cos(\alpha)}$$

#### Forces onto the block

Again with the Newton's Second Law, $$\sum\vec{F}_m = \vec{n}_{\text{M onto m}} + \vec{F}_g = m\vec{a}_m$$

- By Newton's Third Law, we'll have that $\vec{n}_{\text{M onto m}} = -\vec{n}_{\text{m onto M}}$ which had previously been written down, so $$<n^*\sin(\alpha), n^*\cos(\alpha)>$$
- $\vec{F_g}$ is again simply the weight of the smaller mass $m$ so $$<0, -mg>$$

So going component-wise again, $$
\begin{array}{cc}
  \Bigg \lbrace & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      ma_{mx} = \\
      ma_{my} =
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{array}{cc}
      n_y^*\sin(\alpha) =mg\tan(\alpha) \\
      n_y^*\cos(\alpha)-mg
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Which is a surprising result, since as $\alpha \rightarrow 90^\circ$ then $a_{mx} \rightarrow \infty$, but I suppose plausible if the duration of contact is falling to zero.

Another elegant result would be that the block would apparently fall with constant velocity, $ma_{my}=n^*\cos(\alpha)-mg=({mg \over \cos(\alpha)})\cos(\alpha)-mg = 0$ but would float indefinitely if started from rest, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please clarify where are you putting the $x$ and $y$ axis?

Comment: Standard, $y$ is up, and $x$ to the right. I do have the solutions manual, I'm just curious about what forbids how I constrained the problem. Increasing $\alpha$ raises the height of $y$ and creates a negative slope towards the terminating point of the wedge.

Comment: I suppose the book calls this out, it's always better to assume you *don't* know the normal force.